# Dual boot up (windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04) issue- windows default OS but need Ubuntu as default

Tags: 16.04

I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed in UEFI mode on my laptop. During start up I had to press enter, then press F9 and then select Ubuntu to get to Ubuntu.

STATUS:
F10 key: In system configuration (boot option): I selected Secure boot and in UEFI boot order: OS boot manager is listed as the first entry.

F9 Key: Boot manager window- Boot options menu list:

1. OS Boot manager (UEFI) - Windows boot manager.
2. OS Boot manager (UEFI) - Ubuntu.
3. Boot from EFI file.

My question: How do I avoid pressing enter key, then F9 key and then Ubuntu from boot manager window?

I want HP Laptop to give me OS choice during startup without pressing F9. 
That is in Boot manager window I want Ubuntu listed as the first entry. I tried to move this to the top by pressing F5/F6 but it doesn't work. Looks like windows boot manager is hardcoded as priority OS during startup.

any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase boot priority of Ubuntu in Bios setup.The steps may vary from one device to another.Press F9 in your laptop.You will see boot priority there.As you  said windows is on priority 1 and Ubuntu is on 2.Change their order.Should work fine then.

Comment: Solution worked for me just now, Ubuntu 19.04 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repair the boot from ubuntu then it will show the list of os options and you dont have to go into bios always for selecting the os. 
For repair the boot follow the link
[Link given below](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Hope it will help you